# how to color the first word in a string (tkinter) using tag_config

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is the one line of code I use, it works for coloring the whole text, but how do I only color the beginning word?

```
widget.tag_config('red', foreground="red")
```

I haven't tried much

Comment: Why haven’t you tried much?

Comment: I can't find much about using tag_config

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+text+highlight+word+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but how do I only color the beginning word?

Type in entry box and press enter.
Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

entryWords = tk.StringVar()
words = []

def storeWords(event: None)-> None:
  global words
  words = entryWords.get().split()
  new_word(0)
  
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entryWords, width=30) 
entry.bind("<Return>", storeWords)
c.create_window(200, 50, window=entry)
entry.focus()                           
  
def new_word(i: int) -> int:
  if i == len(words):
    i = 0
    
  word = words[i]
  middle = (len(word)+1) 
  c.itemconfigure(t1, text=word[:middle])
  
  root.after(1000, lambda: new_word(i+1))

t1 = c.create_text(200,100,text='', anchor='e', font=("Courier", 25), fill='red')

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]